# Cannot retreive issue details from Jira API

Tags: c#, linq, jira-rest-api

I'm having some issues after recently converting our code for getting Jira issue (singular) details from SOAP to their REST API.  We have a simple button in a Window form that is supposed to "refresh" the Jira information for a given Jira ID.  Here's the code:

```
public Atlassian.Jira.Issue GetJiraDetails(string drNumber)
{
    try
    {
        // This line requires credentials for the Username and password
        var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(CloudJiraAddress, userName, password);

        jira.Issues.MaxIssuesPerRequest = 9000;

        // use LINQ syntax to retrieve issues
        var query = (from i in jira.Issues.Queryable
                        where i.Key == drNumber
                        select i).FirstOrDefault();

        return query;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This used to work with SOAP but now I get the following error:
[image]

The project is in Visual Studio 2019 and uses the NuGet package Atlassian.SDK 10.6.0.  I've also verified that the credentials (link, username, API Token as password) are correct with Insomnia and Postman (am able to get results).

**UPDATE**
I tried just grabbing specific fields and oddly enough it works:

```
    public DateTime? GetDateCreated(string drNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            // This line requires credentials for the Username and password
            var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(CloudJiraAddress, userName, password);

            jira.Issues.MaxIssuesPerRequest = 9000;

            // use LINQ syntax to retrieve issues
            var dateToSave = (from i in jira.Issues.Queryable
                              where i.Key == drNumber
                              select i.Created).FirstOrDefault();

            if (dateToSave != null)
                return ((DateTime)dateToSave).AddHours(-4);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

So now I'm wondering why it can retrieve individual issue fields but not the entire issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Jira Cloud won't allow you to use basic auth with a password today,
> that functionality was deprecated a few years back.  You could create
> an [API Token](https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/) first, and then follow the steps over in [Basic Auth
> for REST APIs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/).

Excerpted from [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Best-practice-to-connect-amp-auth-against-JIRA-s-OAUTH2-with-C/qaq-p/1790566)

You should use it as such

```
var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(url, username, Token, settings);
```

Comment: My bad for the misinformation, I am using an API Token...I've updated the original question to contain that.

Comment: @Robert are you using the token in lieu of the password?

Comment: Yes...as recommended by this thread on the Atlassian support site: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Issue-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permission-to-see-it/qaq-p/2347425?utm_source=atlcomm&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=mentions_reply&utm_content=topic